# Buying a Gun for a Californian

Tags: california, firearms, utah, second-amendment

I am a California native, currently attending school in Utah, and have been considering getting a Concealed Carry License as a non-resident of the State. In doing research, however, it appears that, because I am a legal resident of California, I cannot purchase a gun in Utah. Now, I am aware, that it is legal for a private citizen (not a licensed gun retailer) to purchase a firearm as a gift for someone else, as long as that someone else is not a [convicted felon](https://www.frontiercarry.org/buying-and-selling-ut.html). What I'm wondering then, is whether it would be legal for, say, my wife, a Utah resident, to purchase a gun on my behalf?

Comment: How does Utah determine residency? Note that residency in terms of the school (for in vs. out of state tuition) is not necessarily the same as residency in terms of the state itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot legally purchase a gun in Utah due to any restriction, such as residency, and you engage someone else to knowingly buy or gift you a gun (such as a "straw man" purchase from a dealer or private sale), that is illegal.

From the same link you posted *(my emphasis)*:

> Can I buy a firearm as a gift for someone?
>
> Yes, as long as the receiver is not a prohibited person and the
>   gifting *is not being used to circumvent* a background check *or other
>   laws*. Calling a purchase intended in place of another is a straw
>   purchase.